# How to reflect the updating of the status of the submitted suggestion immediately?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a simple intranet suggestion box system that lets the employees being able to submit their ideas through it. Now, for the System Admin, I list all the submitted suggestions with showing the employee name, username, division, suggestion title, suggestion description with adding one column that shows the status. For the Status column, it will show a DropDownList that contains the possible options such as Accepted, Rejected ...etc

Here I have the following problem; when the admin selects one of status, it will be changed but not immediately and I don't know why. How did I know? I have another GridView under this table that shows the submitted suggestions in the last month. if admin accepts for example one of the submitted suggestions. This suggestion will not be displayed event after refreshing page and I don't know why.

My ASP.NET:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" 
                        width="950px" CssClass="mGrid"
                        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" 
                        RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                        OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold = "true" ForeColor="Black" Height="20px"/> 
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                    SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" 
                    SortExpression="Username" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DivisionShortcut" HeaderText="Division" 
                    SortExpression="DivisionShortcut" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
                                          Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#006666" AppendDataBoundItems="false" 
                                          DataTextField="Status" DataValueField="ID" AutoPostBack="true" 
                                          OnDataBound="DropDownList_DataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged ="DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT     dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.ID, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Title, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Description, dbo.employee.Name, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username, 
                      dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut
FROM         dbo.employee INNER JOIN
                      dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Divisions ON dbo.employee.DivisionCode = dbo.Divisions.SapCode"
                      FilterExpression="[DivisionShortcut] like '{0}%'">

                      <FilterParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDivision" Name="DivisionShortcut" 
                                                 PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                    </FilterParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <%--For the DropDownList--%>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [SafetySuggestionsStatus]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My Code-Behind:

```
protected void DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        int suggestionStatus = int.Parse(ddl.SelectedValue);
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;
        string strID = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["ID"].ToString();
        int ID = Int32.Parse(strID);
        //For inserting the status in the database
        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdbTest;Integrated Security=True";
        string updateCommand = "UPDATE SafetySuggestionsLog  SET [StatusID] = @StatusID WHERE [ID] = @ID";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateCommand, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatusID", suggestionStatus);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
```

**So how to fix this problem to let the status of the submitted suggestion be updated immediately?**

**EDIT:**

```
protected void DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        int suggestionStatus = int.Parse(ddl.SelectedValue);
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;
        string strID = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["ID"].ToString();
        int ID = Int32.Parse(strID);
        //For inserting the status in the database
        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdbTest;Integrated Security=True";
        string updateCommand = "UPDATE SafetySuggestionsLog  SET [StatusID] = @StatusID WHERE [ID] = @ID";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateCommand, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatusID", suggestionStatus);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: that is absolutely normal behaviour - you need to update the gridview (either by refreshing it OR by polling etc.).

Comment: Btw, your `conn.Close();` is redundant with using-statement.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind your GridView to it's DataSource again after you've changed it. Because you're using a declarative DataSource, a simple `GridView1.DataBind()` should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help but where I should put it? And should I remove the declarative DataSource?

Comment: @AliAhmed: at the end of `DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged`. No, either use your SqlDataSource and call GridView.DataBind or do it manually with ADO.NET(what i prefer), retrieve the rows from dbms again, set the GridView's DataSource and then call DataBind.

Comment: I did it like shown above and when I updated the status for one of the suggestions, that line of code will update the status of all suggestions and I don't know why.

Comment: @AliAhmed: That line will update nothing, it will only get the datasource from dbms with your meanwhile updated row(s) and refreshes the GridView. Have you set a breakpoint here to see if it gets called multiple times?

Comment: So how to do it? Could you please provide me with code snippet?

Comment: @AliAhmed: What code shall i provide, the way you should use the debugger? Your code looks fine, at least i cannot see the problem.